# Отобразить на карте маршрут из 5-ти точек GPS координат - Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api

Отобразить на карте в планшете маршрут из 5-ти точек массива GPS координат используя Google Map API. (Маршрут рассчитывается сервером Google).
массив координат:

```
new LatLng[] {
   new LatLng(49.9166, 36.4105),
   new LatLng(50.1006, 36.1301),
   new LatLng(50.0342, 36.174),
   new LatLng(50.0404, 36.3656),
   new LatLng(49.934, 36.4111)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Маршрут рисуется с помощью точек и линий. Вот [документация](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/shapes) и [пример](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/PolylineDemoActivity.java).

Построением маршрута занимается отдельный сервис - [Direction](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/). Если коротко, то нужно сформировать и выполнить HTTP-запрос. В ответ придет JSON с координатами, подсказками и прочими данными. Их надо показать на карте, см. выше.

Есть [либа](https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-GoogleDirectionLibrary), которая формирует запрос, выполняет и парсит результат. Про саму либу ничего не скажу, но у нее есть [пример](https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-GoogleDirectionLibrary/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/akexorcist/googledirection/sample/SimpleDirectionActivity.java), из которого в общем понятна суть происходящего.

Comment: Спасибо. Но это не то, надо не просто соединить точки линиями, а проложить маршрут

Answer (score -1):

Вот код отрисовки маршрута по точкам

```
@Override
public void drawDirect(List<LatLng> points) {
    googleMap.clear();

    PolylineOptions line = new PolylineOptions();
    line.width(8f).color(Color.RED);
    LatLngBounds.Builder latLngBuilder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
        if (i == points.size() - 1) {
            MarkerOptions endMarkerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(points.get(i));
            googleMap.addMarker(endMarkerOptions);
        }
        line.add(points.get(i));
        latLngBuilder.include(points.get(i));
    }
    googleMap.addPolyline(line);
    int size = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    LatLngBounds latLngBounds = latLngBuilder.build();
    CameraUpdate track = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(latLngBounds, size, size, 25);
    googleMap.animateCamera(track);
}
```

По сути массив точек передаваемый в этот метод это ключевые точки маршрута. А если вам нужно получить эти ключевые точки, то смотрите что написал @tse

Ключевые точки можно получить с помощью такого запроса

```
@GET("maps/api/directions/json")
Call<Object> getDirect(
        @Query("origin") String position,
        @Query("destination") String destination,
        @Query("key") String key,
        @Query("mode") String mode);
```

по такому адресу

```
private final String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/";
```